# why is my lagrangian interpolation not approximating as nearly accurate as Newton's DD approximation?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Here is the set of data:
$(X,Y)= (1,4.75), (2,4), (3,5.25), (5,19.75), (6,36)$

After I approximated to $3$rd order polynomial with Newton's interpolation, it modeled the true behavior of how $X$ and $Y$ are changing. The rate of change of several slopes has come to $0$ after $3$rd order coefficient. I chose my base point to be close to $4$ to get better accuracy because I was asked to evaluate the function at $4$; the result was $22$.
Then I applied Lagrange interpolation and evaluated the $2$nd and $3$rd order polynomial at $4$ but they are straying away from the result I got with Newton's. They were $10.5$ and $10$, respectively. $1$st order matched with Newton's method result, which was $12.5$. What's the reason for this discrepancy? Does that mean Lagrange is not as reliable as Newton's?

Comment: Newton and Lagrange interpolation give you the same polynomial, they just use a different basis. As a consequence, they should have the same result. But then I'm also confused why you use a 3rd order polynomial to interpolate between 5 points. You need a 4th order polynomial for that.

Comment: when i keep on finding the rise over run ratios for b1 and b2 and b3 until there is 2 left, they are equal. so for b4 =0 and 4th order gets reduced back to 3rd. 
However i found i inserted the wrong coefficients in my 2nd and 3rd order polynomial so i changed them and now they have the same results. thank you for the clarification